# Texture atlases limitations on big resolution sprite images with many frames used in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, textures, kobold2d

On what good serves me a texture atlas if my 3D character is big enough and fits only a few on the 4k*4K spritesheet?

Seems like big resolution (420x768px) graphics are not best suited for such textures and used in cocos2d 2 to create nice animations from frames.

So is a 3d engine best suited for heavy sprite animations? Anyone encountered similar limitations, when creating a heavy animation game in cocos2d? Thanks.

Comment: have you considered how much memory these frames consume?

Comment: I approximated that and they would end up consuming quite a lot of RAM, and the biggest drawback is that I can't reduce the quality and size even in TexturePacker because I need the 3D model to be at it's high quality as it was modeled so turns out, texture atlases can't help much in this context, thus resorting to a 3d engine like Unity seems no doubtly to solve it, although cocos2d with it's BatchNode methods etc. is absolutely great for smaller in size 2d graphics art. :)

Comment: you do know that the high resolution textures really only make a difference when you zoom really up close onto the 3d model?

Comment: but how about exporting the POD model from Maya into cocos3d? Isn't it a easier solution than creating a lot of 2D texture atlases which can get tricky at some point? I mean I have to go though documentation of cocos3d now.